# is dll hooking and dll hijacking the same concept?

Tags: windows, appsec

I'm very confused after reading all about these concepts, want an example so as to the concept of dll hooking/hijacking and dll injection is clear!
Is dll hijacking/hooking the samething?!

Please help me with an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not the same.

**DLL injection** is one process forcing a different, already executing process to load a DLL.

**DLL hijacking** is malicious software taking advantage of a program not specifying the exact location of a DLL it is loading and having it load a different DLL than the program intended.

**DLL hooking** is where an application takes over the entry points of a DLL so that it can intercept API calls.

Injection and hooking may or may not be malicious, injection is nearly always malicious.